# Fluid dynamics textbook discussing Hele-Shaw flow

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, textbook-recommendation, fluid-dynamics

In [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hele-Shaw_flow) Wikipedia article, Hele-Shaw flow is discussed in some detail. I'd like to find a textbook that discusses Hele-Shaw flow in greater detail. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A mathematics-oriented text book is [Conformal and Potential Analysis in Hele-Shaw Cells](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Conformal_and_Potential_Analysis_in_Hele/y68nodht9RwC?hl=en&gbpv=0), by Gustafsson and Vasil'ev (2006).

> This monograph aims at giving a presentation of recent and new ideas
> that arise from the problems of planar fluid dynamics and which are
> interesting from the point of view of geometric function theory and
> potential theory. In particular, this book is concerned with geometric
> problems for Hele-Shaw flows. Also Hele-Shaw flows on parameter spaces
> (e.g., the Teichmüller space) are treated and connections with string
> theory are revealed. Ultimately, the interaction between several
> branches of complex and potential analysis, and planar fluid mechanics
> is discussed. For most parts of this book the background provided by
> graduate courses in real and complex analysis, in particular, the
> theory of conformal mappings and in fluid mechanics is assumed. There
> are some historical remarks concerning the people that have
> contributed to the topic. The book is as self-contained as possible.